# Math I just cannot translate into code

Tags: python, math

I have a relatively easy function which I have no idea how to translate into code. I already imported the `math` module as I can see that I will need to use `sqrt`, `cos`, and `sin`.

Below is an image of the function

[image: Function]

`altfel` is translated into `else` for this exercise. I understand that you need to use a bunch of `if`/`else` statements but just can't get my head around it.

Comment: This might be of some use -- http://matt.might.net/articles/discrete-math-and-code/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a single `if/else` to ensure `x` and `y` are in the right portion of the domain:

```
In [1]: from math import sqrt, cos, sin
In [2]: def f(x, y):
   ...:     if (x < -1 or x > 3) and (y < -1 or y > 1):
   ...:         return sqrt(y)/(3 * x - 7)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return cos(x) + sin(y)
   ...:
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin

def f(x, y):
    if (x < -1 or x > 3) and (y < -1 or y > 1):
        return sqrt(y) / (3 * x - 7)
    else:
        return cos(x) + sin(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import math

def f(x, y):
    if (x < -1 or x > 3) and (y < -1 or y > 1): # these are the conditions for x and y
        return math.sqrt(y) / (3*x - 7)
    else:
        return math.cos(x) + math.sin(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can use the concatenated from of the comparison operators `a < b < c` to test for an interval, so:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin

def f(x, y):
    if -1 <= x <= 3 and -1 <= y <= 1:
        return cos(x) + sin(y)
    else:
        return sqrt(y) / (3 * x - 7)
```

This seems more readable to me.